# Can't add to json value from another jsonb column

Tags: postgresql-9.5

I need to add to result json new node "myNode"

here query:

```
select  myJsonB || jsonb '{"myNode":"myNode_value"}' as data from myTable
where myJsonB @> '{"id": 11111}'
```

'

And it's work fine. To result json success added new node **myNode** with value **myNode_value**.

Nice.

But I need to set value from another jsonb column (**meta**) Alias **metaValue**. I try this:

```
select  myJsonB  || jsonb '{"myNode" : metaValue}' as data, meta->'accounting'->'checkout'->>'url' as metaValue from myTable
where myJsonB @> '{"id": 11111}'
```

But I get error:

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type json
LINE 1: select  data || jsonb '{"myNode":metaValue}' as data, meta->...
```

E.g. If in column **meta** (jsonb)

```
meta->'accounting'->'checkout'->>'url' = "hello"
```

then in result json in field **myNode** must set value **hello**.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name No. The value of "myNode" must be value from another column "meta". Value is locate on meta->'accounting'->'checkout'->>'url'

Answer (score 0):

I found solution

```
select myJsonB  || jsonb_build_object('checkout', meta->'accounting'->'checkout'->>'url')from myTable
 where myJsonB  @> '{"id": 11111}'
```

I use **jsonb_build_object** and not it's work fine